# Duplicate Object with same identifier Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So here is my problem I'm using Spring Data to handle persistent side of my application, I've no error but I notice a weird thing which I could't understand.

Suppose I have 2 queries with different criteria and there is an object that match the 2 queries so the problem is the object returned by the first query and the other returned by the second aren't referring the same instance hence there are separate instance with the same identifier.

But since it is the same object we should have only one instance it means when the second query executed and the result include an object that already loaded by the first query it should use that instance not creating new one.

Example :

First query : `Id = 21 Object=com.bougsid.app.order.Order@7aea8d88`

Second Query: `Id = 21 Object=com.bougsid.app.order.Order@6eb0e570`

So could you please help me to figure out a way I can go through this and preventing create a new instance of an object already loaded.

Comment: What is your data source?

Comment: Are you sure both querys are in the same transaction?, are you sure the first object is not being detached in anyway?... Can you show for us a chunk of code?

Comment: @dovy Im using MySQL

Comment: @Dani I'm using spring data so I don't need to take a care of any transaction they already managed by spring. here the two queries :

`List<Order> findByCreationDateBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end);`

`List<Order> findAll();`

Comment: You should post your source code what make you stuck. Make your question clear and easy to answer. I afraid/ I guess that, in your `persistence.xml`, you set something enable auto create = true.

Comment: I'm using spring boot here what my application.properties looks like :
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sm
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`